# Node-Serialport: Unable to handle incoming data with RxJS Observable when timeout is applyied

Tags: node.js, rxjs, serial-port, node-serialport, node-streams

I am currently working on a NodeJS project using the [`serialport` module](http://serialport.io) in conjunction with [RxJS Observables](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). The intended 'flow'/use case is as follows:

1. name of a serial port `portName` is sent via the serial port
2. since RxD and TxD are linked to each other, the data is 'echoed' on the hardware side
3. data is read through the serial port
4. incoming data is handled by the [`readline-parser`](https://serialport.io/docs/en/api-parser-readline) and passed to an [RxJS Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)
5. if read `data` is equal to the previously sent `portName`, observable is not longer needed and will be completed by `observer.complete()`

I was able to implement the above mentioned flow, but need to do some further implementations like

1. timeout if no data is received within a given period of time
2. retries to send command again in case of timeout or other errors

I am working on the timeout implementation and tried both [NodeJS' `setTimeout()`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/) and [RxJS' own `timeout` function](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html). When applying any kind of timeout function, the data does not seem to be read/retrieved by the serial port which in turn raises a timeout error.

Assuming that there is no data, this seems to be quite fine at first glance, since the timeout does do what it should do. However, I was able to double-check that the desired data is sent to the port by using not only an emulated serial port in software, but also by using two CP2102 USB-to-Serial-converters (see comments in code for further details):

```
'use strict';
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const { interval } = require('rxjs');
const { timeout } = require('rxjs/operators');
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');


// `tries` is needed for later implementation of communcation retries
const myObservable = (portName, tries) => {
  const port = new SerialPort(portName);
  const parser = port.pipe( new Readline() );
  port.write(`${portName}\n`);

  return Rx.Observable
    .create( (observer) => {
      parser.on('data', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
        console.log(`Detection will be: ${data == portName} (${data} vs. ${portName})`);
        if (data == portName)
        {
          port.close( (err) => {
            if (err)
            {
              console.log(`Error on closing serial port: ${err}`);
              observer.error(err);
            }
          });
          observer.complete();
        }
      })
    })
    // `timeout` is needed for later implementation of communication timeout, see comment at end of code
    // .pipe(timeout(10000))
}


const myObserver = {
  next:     x => console.log(`got data from observable: ${x}`),
  error:    err => console.error(`something wrong occurred: ${err}`),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
};


console.log('before subscribe');
const sub = myObservable('/dev/tty.usbserial-FTG7L3FX', null).subscribe(myObserver);
// double-checked that data is sent by using software (created an emulated pair of virtual serial ports with `socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0`)
// --> data is sent, but not read/retrieved when either using `setTimeout` or RxJS' own `timeout()`
// const sub = myObservable('/dev/ttys003', null).subscribe(myObserver);
// double-checked that data is sent by using hardware interfaces (used two CP2102 modules with pairwise-crossed RxD and TxD)
// --> data is sent, but not read/retrieved when either using `setTimeout` or RxJS' own `timeout()`
// const sub = myObservable('/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART', null).subscribe(myObserver);
console.log('after subscribe');


// when commenting the following `setTimeout()` data is retrieved, but does not work with `setTimeout()`
// so tried to use RxJS' `timeout()` operator --> not working either
// setTimeout(() => {
//   sub.unsubscribe();
//   console.log('unsubscribed');
// }, 10000);
```

What am I missing here? Why is data sent when not using any kind of timeout but is not when applying a timeout function?

---

*Updates due to further investigation:*

1. When `timeout()` is applied, the data is sent after the timeout duration which means that the timeout fires both sending data and exiting the observable since it is timed out. So the `.timeout()` does not seem to be applied to the returned `Rx.Observable`, but to the whole function `myObservable`.

Comment: Have I understood correctly that your code works completely as expected up until you set the timeout at the end to unsubscribe?

Comment: It looks like the timeout is not applied to the Observable, but to the complete function returning the Observable. This is not the desired behavior, since the data is sent with the same function. So the data should be sent to the serial device, waiting for incoming data/answer until timeout.

Comment: I mean the `setTimeout`. Let's forget about `timeout` operator in observable function, does your code work as expected if you don't set the timeout that unsubscribes?

Comment: Without any kind of timeout, anything works as desired. Code with commented lines in my question does what it should and was the basis for further timeout implementation.